# Parameterising a paraboloid

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, parametrization

I am given this question below, and I was hoping for some guidance as to why I am getting my answer incorrect...

Question:

Consider the flux integral

∬Sf⋅n̂ dS,
where f= [0,y,2z] and S is the paraboloid surface shown below.

[image]

This paraboloid has height 2 and maximum radius 2.

(a) Based on cylindrical polar coordinates, enter the parameterisation

p(r,t)=(x(r,t),y(r,t),z(r,t)),
such that 0≤r<2 and 0≤t<2π gives the paraboloid surface above.

So, my answer is: [r*cos(t), r*sin(t), 0.5*r^2*(cos(t)^2) + 0.5*r^2*(sin(t))^2], and when I plotted this, my graph seems to be identical to the above graph, yet my answer is wrong. My teacher said that I need to consider the height with the paraboloid when the radius is 2, and that I am only a constant out...

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

The paraboloid can be expressed as

$$x^2+y^2=2z$$

which can be parametrized as below,

$$x(r,t)=r\cos t$$
$$y(r,t)=r\sin t$$
$$z(r,t)=\frac 12 r^2$$

You may just have to simplify your $z$ function.